# How to return a mock to subclass with mockConstruction?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, junit5

This could be considered a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66592084/return-a-specific-mock-from-a-mocked-constructor-with-mockito) for which there are no answers, so I will try with an example.

I'm trying to mock a class with native methods without having to refactor the code, for example:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

public class A {
    public A() throws Exception {
        init();
    }
    private native void init() throws Exception;
    public native void execute(double[][] matrix) throws Exception;
}
```

If I try this test:

```
    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        A a = mock(A.class);
        a.execute(new double[][]{{0.0}});
    }
```

I get this error because of native method:

```
[ERROR] test1  Time elapsed: 4.391 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void com.mycompany.app.A.execute(double[][])'
        at com.mycompany.app.ATest.test1(ATest.java:14)
```

My idea was to extends the class and mock the last one, for example:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

public class B extends A {
    public B() throws Exception {
    }
    public void execute(double[][] matrix) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

and the following test works:

```
    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        A a = mock(B.class);
        a.execute(new double[][]{{0.0}});
    }
```

Now I have to make a test for a method using class A, for example:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

public class C {
    public void execute(double[][] matrix) throws Exception {
        A a = new A();
        a.execute(matrix);
    }
}
```

and the following test:

```
    @Test
    public void test3() throws Exception {
        try (MockedConstruction<A> a = mockConstruction(A.class)) {
            C c = new C();
            c.execute(new double[][]{{0.0}});
        }
    }
```

fails in the same way test1 failed:

```
[ERROR] test3  Time elapsed: 0.085 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void com.mycompany.app.A.execute(double[][])'
        at com.mycompany.app.ATest.test3(ATest.java:27)
```

Is there a way to make mockConstruction to return `mock(B.class)` instead of `mock(A.class)` when an instance of A is created?